# Java FX и Eclipse

Tags: java, javafx, eclipse

ребята,я создал fxml сцену в Fx scene ,и исходный код засунул в класс эклипса,но при запуске программы ошибок не выдает,и при этом запускается белое окно,что делать?

Comment: Непонятна суть вопроса. Что значит "засунул исходный код в класс эклипса?" Исходный код чего? Что такое "класс эклипса"? Что описано у вас в fxml? Что вы ожидали увидеть? Приведите минимальные куски кода, которые отражают вашу проблему. И если бы вы поставили метку `java`, ваш  вопрос увидело бы больше людей. Почитайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Вы создали проект Java или JavaFX?